# to hide table if all the data-fields - td with multiple span values are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
$scope.hide_emptytable() = function{
if ($.trim($('.acf-dynamic-table .field').text())=="") {
    $('.acf-dynamic-table').hide();
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-repeat="t in[]">
<table class="acf-dynamic-table">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">t.name</td>
<td class="field"><span>t.ward_no</span> <span>t.street</span> <span>t.city</span> <span>t.state</span> <span>t.postcode</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="t in []">
<table class="acf-dynamic-table">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field"></td>
<td class="field"><span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<span style="display : none">{{hide_emptytable()}}</span>
```

I want to hide the table if column-values with class field are empty. For example second table should be hidden but its not working.
For address, values are inside span within one space between them.

Comment: not sure if its the cause of your problem but: `= function{` is a syntax error you do not have the parameter list, eg `function(){`

Answer (score 0):

I would change hideempty table to return a boolean and use ng-if="hide_emptytable" on the table.

```
$scope.hide_emptytable() = function{
    return ($.trim($('.acf-dynamic-table .field').text())=="") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code should be

```
$scope.hide_emptytable = function(){
   return $.trim($('.acf-dynamic-table .field').text()) == "";      
}
```

then you should use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

```
ng-show = hide_emptytable()
```

**Advice** to you don't mix jquery with angularjs.Angularjs uses MVVM pattern and you can sufficiently make use of angular function to achieve what you want instead of writing `hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with this code.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.acf-dynamic-table .field')
  .has('span')
  .each(function(){
    if($(this).children().not(':empty').length == 0)
      $(this).parents('table').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='print'></div>
<div ng-repeat="t in[]">
  <table id='1' class="acf-dynamic-table">
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field">t.name</td>
      <td class="field"><span>t.ward_no</span> <span>t.street</span> <span>t.city</span> <span>t.state</span> <span>t.postcode</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="t in []">
  <table id='2' class="acf-dynamic-table">
    <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field"></td>
      <td class="field"><span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```